# Python Eclipse Code Analysis ignore doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I use Eclipse with PyDev.  I have some tweaks that need to be made to Pep8.  I have monkeyed around with this and thought I made some progress, but I really don't know how this works.

Current problem is that I would like to get PyDev warnings to stop coming up when I don't match pep8 indents.  I use 2 spaces instead of 4.  The weird thing is that I don't get them in every case.  It seems like I successfully turned them off in some places, but not others.  I would like to turn off E121.  I have a pylint file.

1. I have tried --ignore in the PYDev->Editor->CodeAnalysis settings.
2. I have tried turning off/on PyDev->Editor->CodeStyle->CodeFormatter.
3. I have tried right clicking the container folder and doing PyDev->RemoveErrorMarkers, but they come back when the analysis runs again.

What else can I try?  How can I narrow this down?  Would someone please give mye some insight into how this works?

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have configured pep8 using a **setup.cfg** file in my projects. It resides in parallel to the src folder and contains this:

```
[pep8]
max-line-length=100
# pep8 1.6.2 wants all includes at the top:
ignore=E402
```

This way, I get the intended results even if I use pep8 on the command line or from any other editor. You would have to change the ignore line to match the error code you want to suppress.

See the output from pep8 --help:

> Configuration:
>       The project options are read from the [pep8] section of the tox.ini
>       file or the setup.cfg file located in any parent folder of the path(s)
>       being processed.  Allowed options are: exclude, filename, select,
>       ignore, max-line-length, hang-closing, count, format, quiet, show-
>       pep8, show-source, statistics, verbose.

Comment: I added the file in the same folder that the code is in.  There is no change.  The contents is just the [pep8] line and ignore=E121.  Do I need to configure anything in the preferences?  Is my installation just trashed??

Comment: Does pep8 on the command line correctly ignore the error? And is the error shown in Eclipse really a pep8 error or is it of another type?

Comment: Pep8 works on the command line as it should.  The error in eclipse references pep8 id's, so yes.  I hate to say it, but Eclipse is still a bit of a mystery to me.